# How can I Recover funds sent to a contract created with remix.etherum.org?

Tags: contract-development, remix, bsc

Trying to get experience on blockchain and smartcontracts, I created a contract on remix.etherum.org. I sent funds to that contract and now the funds are stagnant, in limbo. Since I am the contract owner but the constructo did not give a private key, is there a way to reverse transaction or withdraw funds from the contract address to my wallet address -that is the owner of the contract?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to recover the funds from a smart contract if there isn't any function to do so. The only way to recover the funds is to contact the token creator. Tether (USDT) for example, would help you recover funds stuck in a contract. Not all tokens have such support though. All the best